# Please explain to me this weird React syntax

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to find what this React syntax means:

```
useRef<Position[]>([]).current
```

I was trying to understand some code I found in a function:

```
export const Example = () => {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(initialColors);

  // We need to collect an array of height and position data for all of this component's
  // `Item` children, so we can later us that in calculations to decide when a dragging
  // `Item` should swap places with its siblings.
  const positions = useRef<Position[]>([]).current;
  const setPosition = (i: number, offset: Position) => (positions[i] = offset);

  // Find the ideal index for a dragging item based on its position in the array, and its
  // current drag offset. If it's different to its current index, we swap this item with that
  // sibling.
  const moveItem = (i: number, dragOffset: number) => {
    const targetIndex = findIndex(i, dragOffset, positions);
    if (targetIndex !== i) setColors(move(colors, i, targetIndex));
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {colors.map((color, i) => (
        <Item
          key={color}
          i={i}
          color={color}
          setPosition={setPosition}
          moveItem={moveItem}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

The code was in this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-drag-to-reorder-pkm1k?from-embed) in Example.tsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `typescript` code that means:

```
const positions = useRef<Position[]>([]).current
```

Hey make me a reference (`React.useRef`) of type `Position[]` (an array of `Positions`), initialize it's `current` property with an empty array `[]` and assign `current` to a `const` named `positions`. So when you do:

```
console.log(positions) // []
```